# How to make borders for two columns as a whole in Bootstrap3?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

My codes can be previewed [here](http://www.bootply.com/rhc8Ee9UvS) (Bootply)

The HTML part looks like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <a href="#a">
      <div class="my-border">
        <div class="col-md-3">A</div>
        <div class="col-md-3">A1</div>
      </div>
    </a>

    <div class="my-border">
      <a href="#b">
        <div class="col-md-3">B</div>
        <div class="col-md-3">B1</div>
      </a>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

And the CSS part:

```
.my-border
{
  border: medium double rgb(250,0,255)
}
```

I want to make borders like this

```
-----------
|A A1|B B1|
-----------
```

But I found borders are not shown correctly..
[image]
Moreover, I have another two questions:

1. Is it ok to wrap a `<div class="my-custom-class">` between `<div class="col-xx">` and `<div class="row">`. If not, what is the preferred way?
2. Is it ok to wrap a `<a href="my-custom-link">` around serveral `<div>`s? If not, what might be the preferred way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you miss write the point for my-border class, and you must write the content of columns inner in cols divs.

You can too extends the columns divs with your border class.

Look: http://www.bootply.com/73dXGqF2i5

Comment: I fix the `.my-border` part, but the result still seems not correct:  http://www.bootply.com/rhc8Ee9UvS

Comment: Check http://www.bootply.com/73dXGqF2i5, you must place .my-border div into .cols divs. You can write .my-border class with .cols classes together.

Comment: that is the point.. For one `.col-xx` div, it is totally ok as you said, but how to make borders for several divs as a whole?

Comment: The points are: 1. For good practices, an anchor is not a divs container. 2. Between .row and .cols cannot exists other divs. The correct structure is .row > .col-xx and the rest of stuff as children, because the grid needs this behavior. You have many ways but the more easy is repeat the .my-border class per .col-xx or create a table. I hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: [*Solution*](http://www.bootply.com/s4H926vy1z)

**CSS**

```
 .my-border
  {
  border: medium double rgb(250,0,255)
  }
```

**HTML**

```
 <div class="container">
 <div class="row">
 <center>
 <a href="#a">
 <div class="my-border">
 <div class="col-md-3">A</div>
 <div class="col-md-3">A1</div>
 <a href="#b">
 <div class="col-md-3">B</div>
 <div class="col-md-3">B1</div>
 </a>
 </div>
 </a>
 </center>
  </br>
 <div class="my-border">


 </div>

 </div>

 </div>
```